# Why is RStudio showing this error when I run server_site() with Hugo?

Tags: r, web, rstudio, hugo

Three months ago, I created my website through Rstudio using Hugo, and everything went fine. But now that I want to add some posts, I'm having an error when I run `blogdown:::server_site()`, concretely:

```
    C:/Users/AppData/Roaming/Hugo/0.79.1/hugo.exe server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t personal-web -D -F --navigateToChanged
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "home" failed: execute of template failed: template: index.html:1:3: executing "index.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: execute of template failed: template: partials/header.html:3:4: executing "partials/header.html" at <partial "head/head" .>: error calling partial: "C:\Users\R\website\layouts\partials\head\head.html:5:43": execute of template failed: template: _internal/opengraph.html:5:43: executing "_internal/opengraph.html" at <.>: range can't iterate over /image
```

I checked the link in Github that apparently fix this error https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/da1321100ffb9ee0f729ff060ba079ff7edb53cc but I don't see where the serve.R file is located on my computer, so I cannot edit it. Therefore, I don't know what to do in order to solve this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try re-installing the package? The file in question should update then.

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting the blogdown package and re-installing it from the github repository, and still have the same errors when I run server_site().